How to solve redis error in my node.js project on localmachine
Redis error. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379
}
I am setup node.js project on my localmachine but I am getting above error and I am not setup any redis in my localmachine.
I need to proper solution for this question

It looks like your Node.js application is attempting to connect to a Redis server on localhost but cannot establish a connection.
You'll need to set up a Redis server, which can be either in a local or remote environment.
Below, I'll provide a guide on how to set up Redis locally, which is useful during the development phase.
macOS

Install Redis using Homebrew:
brew install redis

This command downloads and installs the latest Redis server.

Start Redis service automatically:
brew services start redis

This ensures Redis starts now and reboots.


Linux (Debian-based distributions)

Update your package lists:
sudo apt-get update


Install Redis:
sudo apt-get install redis-server

This installs the Redis server.

Start the Redis service:
sudo systemctl start redis.service

This command starts the Redis server.


Windows

Download the Redis installation from Microsoft's archive on GitHub.
Follow the installation instructions provided in the repository to set up Redis on Windows.

Docker

Run Redis in a Docker container:
docker run --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis

This command pulls the latest Redis image from the Docker Hub and runs it in a detached mode, mapping port 6379 on your host to port 6379 in the container, allowing local access.

Verify Installation
Regardless of your installation method, you can check if Redis is running by using:
redis-cli ping

If Redis is running, it should respond with PONG.
